# how to open the Navigation drawer on the click of menu Icon?

Tags: cosmicmind

i am using navigation controller and Navigation drawer controller on the same UIViewController but i don't know how to open the navigation drawer on the click of the menu button. Someone suggest me please.

Comment: I am pushing an example with this in a moment.

Comment: why it is down voted??

Comment: No idea. This is a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referenced from this sample project [NavigationDrawer](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/tree/master/Examples/Programmatic/NavigationDrawerController) you can add handlers to a button that use the `toggle*` methods.

```
@objc
internal func handleMenuButton() {
    navigationDrawerController?.toggleLeftView()
}

@objc
internal func handleMoreButton() {
    navigationDrawerController?.toggleRightView()
}
```

The toggle methods observe the state of the `NavigationDrawer` and then switch to the opposite state. For example, if it is `opened` it will `close`, and if it is `closed` it will open.

If you want to open or close no matter the state, then you can use the open* and close* methods directly.

```
navigationDrawerController?.openLeftView()
navigationDrawerController?.closeLeftView()

navigationDrawerController?.openRightView()
navigationDrawerController?.closeRightView()
```

You can see the entire source code [here](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/blob/master/Examples/Programmatic/NavigationDrawerController/NavigationDrawerController/RootViewController.swift).

That's it, all the best :)

Comment: Please mark the answer, so others know this is the correct solution. Thank you :)